# How to check whether a DEPENDS in `add_custom_command` will be generated by another `add_custom_command`

Tags: cmake

Please see the below minimal example,

```
if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a.txt)
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b.txt
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a.txt
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/a.txt
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b.txt)
  add_custom_target(copy-a-to-b ALL DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b.txt)
endif()

# this if statement isn't right because b.txt doesn't exist in cmake config time
if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b.txt)
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/c.txt
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b.txt
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b.txt
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/c.txt)
  add_custom_target(copy-b-to-c ALL DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/c.txt)
endif()
```

The goal is to copy `a` to `b`, and then `b` to `c` if `a` exist in the first place. The second `if` check doesn't work because `b` doesn't exist in config time and hence causing `c` not being generated. If I comment out the second `if` check, I got an error `copy-b-to-c.rule' exited with code 1` as expected if `a` doesn't exist in the first place. Is there a way to alter the second `if` check so that it checks whether `b` would be generated by another `add_custom_command` elsewhere?

Comment: so why not just move it all inside the first `if()`?

Comment: Then don't copy a to b if b exists. Overall, if b.txt is newer than a.txt, CMake will not execute the command anyway. Overall, why do you check if the source a.txt? Check if the destination b.txt does not exist, if it doesn't, then generate, same with c.txt. Bottom line, _you_ have to specify what you want to do. It is unclear to me what is the exact question or what eactly the behavior are you searching for.

Comment: "_The goal is to copy a to b, and then b to c if a exist in the first place_" you can't just make this all happen in the same custom command? (why?)

Comment: @user this is obviously a dumbed down minimal example, I am writing a cmake function that uses `add_custom_command` to do some complicated things, the input used to be some files that are guaranteed to be available either in build time or config time, now some input could totally be non-existent, so I need to guard against the situation where the input doesn't exist, but still need to make it run if the input will actually be available during build time. Is that clear enough?

Comment: @KamilCuk let me try to explain better, I am searching a `if` that can detect whether a file exist in config time or whether a file will be generated during build time. If that condition is true, my function would do something to the file, if that condition is false, my function would do nothing. Hope that's clear now.

Comment: You present such usage of `if` in the code in your question. What is left is deciding what exactly is the behavior that you want to implement.

Comment: what about moving to `execute_process`? That way it'll be done at configure time instead of build time. The con of that is it'll no longer be done at build time, so if the source dependency changes, you need to reconfigure.